# This is Java operator precedence code. I can not get it's output properly

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I can not understand this code output. I tried many time. But i failed to get compile answer.plz some body can explain how to solve it.

```
System.out.println(4%5*3-4/7+4%2-5/(5*4%5)); //Line 2 
System.out.println(5-8%4*5(5/8*(3%4)*4)+8/4+1); //Line 3 
System.out.println(1.5%2.1-5.4*1.1/(5.4%5)); //Line 4 
System.out.println((5+4)%4+(5/8.0)+4); //Line 5 
System.out.println(5-4*6(5%4-3)*5+6/(1.0/2.0)-5*4); //Line 6 
System.out.println(7+3-4*4%6+4*2.5-3%2); //Line 7 
System.out.println((2-5%5)-10.8%5.1*5*4); //Line 9
```

Comment: `5(5` is not legal in java, as well as `6(5`. There must be an operator between a number and an opening parenthesis.

Comment: Can you indicate what you understand by one of these lines, so that someone can help you see where you're going wrong?  Otherwise, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

For solving such questions, you need to know the precedence and hierarchy of the operators. Look at this: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/operator-precedence

This will extremely help you solving this question. Solve it calmly and match your answers with output. Also, do put operators between parenthesis and operand (you missed them in line 6).